# Strange resolution on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, resolution, nomodeset

I only just installed Ubuntu 11.10, so excuse me if this question is silly ;-)

I have a Fujitsu Esprimo Mobile V655, nvidia 8200 graphics, and recently installed Ubuntu 11.10 using wubi. I had to modify booting commands to include `nomodeset`; otherwise Ubuntu would not boot.

Now I did set my screen resolution to 1280 x 720, which is the correct resolution for this screen. Still, the display seems imperfect. The font sizes seem unnatural(too large / stretched) and text is quite blurry (especially in Firefox).

Could it have something to do withe the nvidia graphics driver and/or the nomodeset parameter? How can I fix this?

**Update:**

I used `jockey-gtk` to update nvidia to the current version. 
This improved the resolution dramatically (no blurriness, fonts are good). It also means that I no loger need to include `nomodeset`in the boot commands.

However, other problems were brought up by this. It seems that certain files cannot be accessed - icon (images) are missing, some task bars are completely unstyled (grey, block-form, win97 style).

I also get this error message(roughly translated from German, so may be slightly different from actual) every time I reboot: `Could not apply the stored configuration for the monitor: none of the chosen modi is compatible with the available modi`.

I have tried `nvidia-xconfig`,  `unity --reset` , no improvements.

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute the Jockey application (`jockey-gtk` from command line) that will propose you an updated Nvidia driver that may solve your problems. Choose nvidia-current to use the most stable version.

---

After doing this it may be helpful to save and then replace your /etc/X11/Xorg.conf file.

First save your old config file with:

```
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.old
```

Then:

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

After that please reboot.

(Instructions below the line are from the follow-up comments).

Comment: OK so I got mixed results here. The resolution is actually better now (fonts look better, screen less blurry) but instead other graphics are messed up (display windows and task bars look block-y and are grey, like win97 style ^^). I also got the error message `the saved display configuration could not be applied. (...) None of the chosen modi is compatible with the available modi (...)` 
Do you have any other suggestions, or how can I fix this?

Comment: gives the error:

    `fs@ubuntu:~$ nvidia-xconfig`
 
    `Using X configuration file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf".`

`VALIDATION ERROR: Data incomplete in file /etc/X11/xorg.conf.
                  Device section "Default Device" must have a Driver line.`

`ERROR: Unable to write to directory '/etc/X11'.`

Comment: that gives the same error

Comment: ok, do the following: 'sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.old' and then 'sudo nvidia-xconfig'.

Comment: alright, that gave me a warning, but no error. will reboot now and see what happens.

Comment: didn't work .. still have some strange graphic changes (like I mentioned, grey display windows / task bar, ...).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2896/discussion-between-yossile-and-fschmidt)

Comment: rebooted the next morning and the error message is gone, resolution is great -- > thank you again!